# Windows 2012R2 + TFS 2015 Build C++ PDB API call failed, error code '23'

Tags: c++, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

I am currently moving our Build Infrastructure from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 but when I build a solution which includes several C++ Project, some of them exit with following error message:

### [error]osmessage.cpp(0,0): Error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '23' : '(

or

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocinfo(22,0): Error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '23' : '(

There seems to be already a reported bug for Jenkins Build: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9104

The provided Workaround doesn´t work for TFS Build: "I set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe globally in the Jenkins configuration and can confirm that mspdbsrv.exe is not killed any more which works around the problem."

Edit: This problem occurs on Windows 2012 R2 Machine. On windows 7 it is working as it should.

Comment: Are you running the build in parallel?

Comment: i´ve tried using /m:1 /maxcpucount:1 but this doesn´t work neither.
I´ve done some investigation in this topic. This problem occurs only on a Windows Server 2012R2 Machine. On Windows 7 its working without any problems. I also tried to run it with MSBuild from the .net Framework 4 Location (c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe)

Comment: Then did you try it on another Server2012?

Comment: yes. I tried it also on a machine where tfs 2010 builds are running successfully

Comment: This just happened to me on TFS2015 gated build. First time since the setting up the server (~500 builds ago)